# SMTPだけを有効にすると、どうして不正な利用をできるのですか？

Tags: mail

「Yahoo!メールでは不正な利用を防ぐためSMTPだけ有効にすることを許可していません」と掲載されていますが、SMTPだけを有効にするとどうして不正利用できるのですか？
SMTPだけ有効にすることは×なのに、SMTPとIMAPを有効にすることは〇なのはなぜですか？

> ・Yahoo!メールでは不正な利用を防ぐために、SMTPだけ有効にすることを許可していません。

[Yahoo!メールヘルプ](https://support.yahoo-net.jp/PccMail/s/article/H000007321)

> SMTPだけ有効にすることはできません
> Yahoo!メールでは不正な利用を防ぐため、SMTPだけ有効にすることは許可していません。SMTPを含めすべて無効にし、「Yahoo!
> JAPAN公式サービスを利用したアクセスのみ有効にする」に設定を変更しますか？

[IMAP/POP/SMTPアクセス](https://mail.yahoo.co.jp/u/pc/f/)

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるでしょう。[第142回　スパムメール対策　— 後編　最新事情とその対処法 —](https://www.tdk.com/ja/tech-mag/knowledge/142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

認証を必須にすれば、SMTPだけでも不正利用は防げるはずです。

Yahooの記述は、認証に [POP(IMAP) before SMTP](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP) のみを使用していた頃のなごりだと想像します。今でも認証方法がこれなのかも知れません。